# gnuplot : Plotting range of multiple y values for same x value

Tags: range, max, gnuplot, min

My data file has multiple y values for one x value. I need to plot the max and min y value for all the x values. Is there a command in `gnuplot` to do so?

**Eg: data file**

```
      x    y
      1    10          
      2    6
      1    14
      1    12
      2    25
      2    14
```

I would like a plot where 1 on x-axis has 10 and 14 plotted and 2 on y-axis has 6 and 25.

I found stats but that finds the min and max values for the entire data set but not for individual x values.

There is Candlesticks option but that is for a different set of data

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Gnuplot cannot do this. Use an external tool or script to preprocess your data.

Comment: You mean you want to replace all consecutive lines with same x by a single line that has the maximum y value of those? You might do an ugly hack using the serial evaluation operator, but i could not recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnuplot was designed to quick plot preprocessed data.
Under Linux, however, you can take advantage of many ready tools to manipulate your data.
If your dataset is not huge you can choose to use some of them *inline* from `gnuplot`.

`sort` can be one of this (as well as `awk`) here you read 4 times your file.

```
plot  "<sort data.dat -k2 -n   | sort -n -k1 -u" t "Min" \
     ,"<sort data.dat -k2 -n -r| sort -n -k1 -u" t "Max"
```

With `awk` you can do a finer work scanning your file only one time

```
set xlabel "My x axis [a.u.]"
set ylabel "My y axis [a.u.]"
set style fill transparent solid 0.4

plot "< awk '{ Q[$1]++;                   \
  if (Q[$1]==1){ Min[$1]=$2;Max[$1]=$2; } \
  else                                    \
  {  if (Min[$1]>$2) {Min[$1]=$2;}        \
     else {if (Max[$1]<$2) Max[$1]=$2;} } \
  }                                       \
  END {for (i in Min) print i,Min[i],Max[i]}' data.dat " \
  using ($1):($2):($3) w filledcurve  title "Min and Max" lc rgb "#00A000"
```

[image: awk plot]

Notes:

- I purged the 1st line of your file for simplicity
- `plot "< command "` it executes a command and it uses it as input data
- `man sort` and `man awk` to have the full help of the `sort` and `awk` programs
- check [associative arrays in awk](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_12.html) to deeper understand `awk`.